# throwing a debug from chrome extension content script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, stack-trace

### Short version

Trying to write a debug command that returns the call stack, minus the current position. I thought I'd use:

```
try {
    throw new Error(options["msg"])
} catch (e) {
    e.stack.shift;
    throw (e);
}
```

but I don't know how to do it exactly. apparently I can't just `e.stack.shift` like that. Also that always makes it an `Uncaught Error` — but these should just be debug messages.

### Long version

I decided I needed a debug library for my content scripts. Here it is:

#### debug.js

```
var debugKeys = {
    "level": ["off", "event", "function", "timeouts"],
    "detail": ["minimal", "detailed"]
};
var debugState = { "level": "off", "detail": "minimal" };

function debug(options) {
    if ("level" in options) {
        if (verifyDebugValue("level", options["level"]) == false)
            return
    }
    if ("detail" in options) {
        if (verifyDebugValue("detail", options["detail"]) == false)
            return
    }

    console.log(options["msg"]);
}

function verifyDebugValue(lval, rval){
    var state = 10; // sufficiently high
    for (k in debugKeys[lval]) {
        if (debugKeys[lval][k] == rval) {
            return true;
        }
        if (debugKeys[lval][k] == debugState[lval]) { // rval was greater than debug key
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

When you using it, you can change the `debugState` in the code to suit your needs. it is still a work in progress but it works just fine.

To use it from another content script, just load it in the manifest like:

#### manifest.json

```
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "js": ["debug.js", "foobar.js"],
    }
  ],
```

and then call it like:

```
debug({"level": "timeouts", "msg": "foobar.js waitOnElement() timeout"});
```

which generates:

```
foobar.js waitOnElement() timeout debug.js:17
```

And there is my problem. At the moment, it is using the console log and so all the debug statements come from the same debug.js line. I'd rather return the calling context. I imagine I need something like:

```
try {
    throw new Error(options["msg"])
} catch (e) {
    e.stack.shift;
    throw (e);
}
```

but I don't know how to do it exactly. apparently I can't just `e.stack.shift` like that. Also that always makes it an `Uncaught Error` — but these should just be debug messages.

Answer (score 0):

You can't avoid mentioning the line in your `debug.js`, because either using `throw (...)` or `console.log/error(...)` your `debug.js` will be issuing the command.

What you can do, is have some `try-catch` blocks in your code, then in the catch block pass the error object to your debug function, which will handle it according to its `debugState`.

In any case, it is not quite clear how you are using your debug library (and why you need to remove the last call from the stack-trace, but you could try something like this:

1. Split the stack-trace (which is actually a multiline string) into lines.
2. Isolate the first line (corresponding to the last call) that is not part of the error's message.
3. Put together a new stack-trace, with the removed line.

E.g.:

```
function removeLastFromStack(stack, errMsg) {
    var firstLines = 'Error: ' + errMsg + '\n';
    var restOfStack = stack
            .substring(firstLines.length)   // <-- skip the error's message
            .split('\n')                    // <-- split into lines
            .slice(1)                       // <-- "slice out" the first line
            .join('\n');                    // <-- put the rest back together
    return firstLines + restOfStack;
}

function myDebug(err) {
    /* Based on my `debugState` I should decide what to do with this error.
     * E.g. I could ignore it, or print the message only, 
     * or print the full stack-trace, or alert the user, or whatever */
    var oldStack = err.stack;
    var newStack = removeLastFromStack(oldStack, err.message);
    console.log(newStack);
    //or: console.error(newStack);
}

/* Somewhere in your code */
function someFuncThatMayThrowAnErr(errMsg) {
    throw new Error(errMsg);
}

try {
    someFuncThatMayThrowAnErr('test');
} catch (err) {
    myDebug(err);
}
```

<sub>...but I still don't see how removing the last call from the trace would be helpful</sub>